# [gstreamer]: Issue with GstAggregator

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I have written a video aggregator plugin based on GstAggregator.
When I am using the plugin with multiple queue (each queue contains some video scaling), It stuck and not getting the call to 'aggregator' function.

If we reduce the framerate of video input, everything is working perfect.

suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got resolved after handling the QOS event.